# Group by year and get count and total count

Tags: pandas

I essentially have a data frame like this:

```
    year   genre

    2018   drama
    2019   comedy
    2019   drama
    2019   comedy
    2019   comedy
```

I want to group it such that I get the count of each genre by year AND the total count for the year.
Something like this

```
    year   genre  count   total count
    2018   drama  1       1
    2019   comedy 3       4
    2019   drama  1       4
```

What I am doing right now is a simple group by like this

```
    df.groupby(['year', 'genre']).count()
```

But this obviously only gives me a count by the genre. How can I include the total count for the year in this?

I am sorry for any formatting issues.

Comment: I don't see how you count 2018 drama twice? Is that a Typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry should have been 2019.